# Not getting custom document in firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How can i get the users document name in firestore,

```
 db.collection("users").get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
            querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
                console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
            });
        });
```

[firestore console screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykaPG.png)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to get here? It looks like your admin_bot document has no data. Are you trying to print "admin_bot"? Then doc.id should give you that value.

Comment: I am trying to get the name like "admin_bot"

Comment: What does "doc.id" command print out?

Comment: querySnapshot size become 0,no value found

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you indeed have a collection called "users" with at least one document, .e.g:

```
db.collection("users").doc("admin_bot").set({}).then(() => {
    console.log("Document written");
})
```

Running your code will then yield the expected output:

```
db.collection("users").get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
        });
    });
```

> admin_bot  =>  {}

Comment: Thanks @Vadim Yushprakh